# day and month reversed when saving to database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, dao

I use a DatePicker and textfield on a form for the user to select a date and by default it displays in the textfield as dd/mm/yyyy.  Therefore, when I wrote my code I used this format to stay consistent.  But when I save a date like 03/10/2015 (which is the 3rd day of October) it gets saved as March 10th.  Given the following code below, what do I need to change to make the save to the database correctly?

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
  ...
  Dim StartDate As String
  Dim EndDate As String
  Dim SDate As Date
  Dim EDate As Date
  ...
  StartDate = Me.txtStartDate.Value & " " & Me.txtStartTime.Value
  EndDate = Me.txtEndDate.Value & " " & Me.txtEndTime.Value
  SDate = CDate(Format(StartDate, "dd\/mm\/yyyy hh:mm"))
  EDate = CDate(Format(EndDate, "dd\/mm\/yyyy hh:mm"))

  If Me.txtOtherDetails.Value = "" Then
    query1 = "INSERT INTO Shifts (Schedule_ID,Start_Date_Time,End_Date_Time,Location)" & _
    " VALUES (" & ScheduleID & ",#" & SDate & "#,#" & EDate & "#," & LocationID & ")"
  Else
    query1 = "INSERT INTO Shifts (Schedule_ID,Start_Date_Time,End_Date_Time,Location,Other_Details)" & _
    " VALUES (" & ScheduleID & ",#" & SDate & "#,#" & EDate & "#," & LocationID & ",'" & Me.txtOtherDetails.Value & "')"
  End If

  'Debug.Print query1
  ShiftID = ExecuteInsert(query1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the format of the date in the query to `mm/dd/yyyy`, since this is the [format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Date-criteria-doesn-t-work-in-my-query-04d97845-3124-43fe-93cd-9c78670fef76?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) used in the MS Access queries.
So you should change:

```
SDate = CDate(Format(StartDate, "mm\/dd\/yyyy hh:mm"))
EDate = CDate(Format(EndDate, "mm\/dd\/yyyy hh:mm"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been completely mixed up.

If your textboxes have been applied a date/time format, they will hold valid date expressions for date values, and these have to be formatted to valid *string* expressions to be concatenated with the SQL code.

Also, concatenating a date/time value *as is* with SQL will initially force a cast of the value to a string using the default Windows settings which will fail in a non-US environment for dates of the 1th to the 12th.

Thus, this is all you need:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
  ...
  Dim StartDate As String
  Dim EndDate As String
  ...
  StartDate = Format(Me!txtStartDate.Value & " " & Me!txtStartTime.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn")
  EndDate = Format(Me!txtEndDate.Value & " " & Me!txtEndTime.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn")

  If Me!txtOtherDetails.Value = "" Then
    query1 = "INSERT INTO Shifts (Schedule_ID,Start_Date_Time,End_Date_Time,Location)" & _
    " VALUES (" & ScheduleID & ",#" & StartDate & "#,#" & EndDate & "#," & LocationID & ")"
  Else
    query1 = "INSERT INTO Shifts (Schedule_ID,Start_Date_Time,End_Date_Time,Location,Other_Details)" & _
    " VALUES (" & ScheduleID & ",#" & StartDate & "#,#" & EndDate & "#," & LocationID & ",'" & Me!txtOtherDetails.Value & "')"
  End If

  'Debug.Print query1
  ShiftID = ExecuteInsert(query1)
End Sub
```